# using functions defined via exec

Tags: python, exec

I receive python function definitions as strings from a foreign (but trusted) database.  The string contains a definition of the form `def fun(x):`, and possibly other function definitions that might be used in the definition of `fun`.

I would like then to `exec` the code, and use `fun`, as follows:

```
def check_fun(code, first_terms):
    exec(code)
    good = all(fun(key) == value for (key, value) in first_terms)
    return good
```

But python complains:

```
SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'check_fun' it contains a nested function with free variables
```

What should I do instead?

I saw the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9195548/3001761, but I do not understand it.  I tried to replace `exec code` with

```
exec code in globals(), d
```

as suggested there.  Printing `d` just thereafter tells me that `fun` and its helper functions are now in `d`, but executing `fun` raises a `NameError`...

I forgot to add that this is in Python 2.7.

Finally, here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> code = 'def fun(x):\r\n    return helper(x)\r\n\r\n\r\ndef helper(x):\r\n    return "got it", x\r\n'
>>> print code                                                                                         
def fun(x):
    return helper(x)


def helper(x):
    return "got it", x

>>> exec code
>>> fun(1)
('got it', 1)
```

UPDATE:

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/872082/4680581, I tried

```
def check_fun(code, first_terms):
    exec code in globals(), globals()
    good = all(fun(key) == value for (key, value) in first_terms)
    return good
```

which "works".  Of course, now `fun` ends up in the global namespace, which is not ideal.  If I can change this, I'd be done.

SOLUTION:

```
def check_fun(code, first_terms):
    new_code = ('def check(first_terms):\r\n    ' 
                + code.replace('\r\n', '\r\n    ')
                + '\r\n    return all(fun(key) == value for (key, value) in first_terms)')
    exec new_code

    return check(first_terms)
```

looks OK.  (I slightly dislike the amount of mangling done to the string, maybe I can still improve on this...)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9195548/3001761. Problem solving 101: **search for your error message**.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the answer there, but I do not understand it.  I tried

Comment: Then can you **be more specific** about what you did and didn't understand, what you're trying to achieve, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, turned my comment into a proper edit and hit enter by accident...

Comment: *"`fun` and its helper functions are now in `d`"* - then why don't you call `d['fun']`?

Comment: Python complains that the helper functions are not defined.  I need to somehow inject them into the namespace...

Comment: ...`fun = d['fun']`?

Comment: I can call `fun` allright with `d['fun']`, but `d['fun']` cannot see the helper functions... I'll add an example.